# Add a number of day for a given date

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to add a number of day to the date that I give to my form then display it in an empty input.

```
    <div class="col">
      <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date" />
      <input type="number" min="1" max="31" [(ngModel)]="day"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="col">
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" (click)="addDays()"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="result"/>
    </div>
```

The code behind

```
  day: number;
  date: Date;
  result: Date;

  addDays(){
   this.result = this.date.setDate(this.date + this.day);
    console.log(this.result);        
  }
```

I get an error: `this.date.setDate is not a function` because I can't add a number to a date. I checked some topics but didn't get solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  var newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: I know but getDate() gives the current date and I don't want this and it will not work because already give a date.

Comment: it should not give the current date because you do
`new Date(date)`
and not
`new Date()`